# Ruby modules - included do end block

Tags: ruby

There is a module `MyModule`:

```
module MyModule

  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def first_method
  end

  def second_method
  end

  included do
    second_class_method
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def first_class_method
    end

    def second_class_method
    end
  end
end
```

When some class `include`s this module, it will have 2 methods exposed as instance methods (`first_method` and `second_method`) and 2 class methods (`first_class_method` and `second_class_method`) - it is clear.

It is said, that

> `included` block will be executed within the context of the class that
>   is including the module.

What does it mean exactly? Meaning, when exactly would this method (`second_class_method`) be executed?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Here's a practical example.

```
class MyClass
  include MyModule
end
```

When you will include the module in a class, the `included` hook will be called. Therefore, `second_class_method` will be called within the scope of `Class`.

What happens here is

1. `first_method` and `second_method` are included as instance-methods of `MyClass.`

   ```
   instance = MyClass.new
   instance.first_method
   # => whatever returned value of first_method is
   ```
2. The methods of `ClassMethods` are automatically mixed as class methods of `MyClass`. This is a common Ruby pattern, that `ActiveSupport::Concern` encapsulates. The non-Rails Ruby code is

   ```
   module MyModule
     def self.included(base)
       base.extend ClassMethods
     end

     module ClassMethods
       def this_is_a_class_method
       end
     end
   end
   ```

   Which results in

   ```
   MyClass.this_is_a_class_method
   ```

   or in your case

   ```
   MyClass.first_class_method
   ```
3. `included` is a hook that is effectively to the following code

   ```
   # non-Rails version
   module MyModule
     def self.included(base)
       base.class_eval do
         # somecode
       end
     end
   end

   # Rails version with ActiveSupport::Concerns
   module MyModule
     included do
       # somecode
     end
   end
   ```

   It's mostly "syntactic sugar" for common patterns. What happens in practice, is that when you mix the module, that code is executed in the context of the mixer class.

Comment: everything sounds logic, but still.. Lets look at example. What if `second_class_method` implemented as `raise "When am I raised?"`, when will it be raised?

Comment: It will be raised almost immediately, as soon as the includer will include your module. That will actually cause the ruby code parsing process and will cause the interpreter to immediately crash. You can try it yourself.

Answer (score 29):

`included` is called when you include `module` into a class, it is used for defining relations, scopes, validations, ...
It gets called before you even have created object from that class.

example

```
module M
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
 ...
  included do
    validates :attr, presence: true
    has_many :groups
  end
 ...
end
```

Comment: so having validations creates restrictions on where the module can be included?

Comment: why wouldn't it work if you set scopes outside of the include do block? it still will be set in the context of the class that included the module, right?

Comment: it won't be "be set in the context of the class that included the module".
`validates` is a method. any method you run inside a module's body is run in the context of that module at the "load time". what you gonna get is "NoMethodError" because for a module, `validates` doesn't mean much