# self.included – including class methods from a module in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I read this post: [Ruby modules - included do end block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28009772/ruby-modules-included-do-end-block) – but still don't get when you would use the `self.included do ... end` block in a module.

The post says that code in the block will be ran when you include the module, but what's the point of that if a module's sole purpose is to be included? Wouldn't that code need to be run anyway? That block doesn't need to be there in order for that code to be run, right?

What would be the difference between the two below:

```
module M
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
    base.class_eval do
      scope :disabled, -> { where(disabled: true) }
    end
  end

  module ClassMethods
    ...
  end
end
```

vs.

```
module M
  def self.some_class_method
     ...
  end

  scope :disabled, -> { where(disabled: true) }
end
```

Comment: it sounds like included block brings those variables from another module to Module M

Comment: but wouldn't it work without that?

Comment: just try to run a sample with some values to see if it works or not and plz lemme know. **you changed your code?!!!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### What's the difference between the two examples?

The first code block adds the class methods in `ClassMethods` to the including class and calls the `scope` method on it as well. The second one does neither of these things and will result in a `NoMethodError` because the module has no `scope` class method. `self.some_class_method` will not be available on the including class once the module is included.

For the full story on how module inclusion works in Ruby, read my answer here:
[**Inheriting class methods from modules / mixins in Ruby**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45127350/1242470)

#### What's the point of `self.included` if a module's sole purpose is to be included?

Inclusion is not the only purpose of modules. They are also used for other things such as namespacing or simply storing various class methods that are then callable on the module itself.

#### Why doesn't Ruby include class methods automatically?

Theoretically Ruby *could* automatically add all class methods defined in a module to the including class, but in practice that would be a bad idea, because you **would not get to choose anymore** whether you want to include class methods — all class methods would be included every time, whether or not they are intended to be included. Consider this example:

```
module M
  def self.class_method
    "foo"
  end

  def self.configure_module
    # add configuration for this module
  end
end

class C
  include M
end
```

Here, the `configure_module` method is *obviously* not supposed to be added to `C`, as its purpose is to set the configuration for the module object. Yet, if we had auto-inclusion for class methods, you would not be able to prevent it from being included.

**But all instance methods are already included! How is that okay then?**

Instance methods in a module are *only really useful* if they are included into a class, since modules cannot have instances, only classes can. So in a module every instance method is expected to be included somewhere to work.

A "class" method on a module is different, because it can be called on the module itself, so it can be used just fine regardless of whether it's also added to the including class. That is why it is better that you have a choice there.

Comment: Can you explain the reasoning by include "only makes its instance methods available"? Wouldn't it just be easier if they made class methods available too? What's wrong with doing that?

Comment: Is it because including only adds instance methods in the ancestorial lookup, but the class methods still belong to that module?

Comment: Basically yes, this is what I explain in the "how to class methods work" part. I'm writing a more elaborate explanation at the moment.

Comment: Added some additional explanation under "Why doesn't Ruby do this automatically?"

Comment: Thanks for adding it! For your first example, we can't control what instance methods get inherited, so why do we need to control what class methods get inherited? And for the 2nd example, why would it be bad if we answered 'yes' to all of your cases. If the coder decides to change M1 inside of class C, then yeah it should also be in class C. And the same goes for M2's singleton_class

Comment: Instance methods in a module are _only really useful_ if they are included into a class, so there it's expected that we'll want to include all of them. In the 2nd example (now removed - it was more confusing than useful), I guess you could answer all those questions with _yes_, but the resulting behavior would be very difficult to implement given the current class/module object model of Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

```
module M
  # self.included is the hook which automatically runs when this module is included
  def self.included(base)
    puts 'this will be printed when this module will be included inside a class'
    base.extend ClassMethods
    base.class_eval do
      scope :disabled, -> { where(disabled: true) }
    end
  end

  def print_object_class
    self.class.name # here self will be the object of class which includes this module
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def print_class_name
      self.name # Here self would be the class which is including this module
    end
  end
end
```

I tried to modify the above `module` to help you understand how a module(concern) can be helpful in code reusability

`self.included` is a hook which runs automatically when a module is included inside a class.

any method declare in the `module ClassMethods` will become class methods for the class including this module

any method declare outside the `module ClassMethods` will become instance methods for the class including this module

For Ex suppose there is a class Product and you have included the module in it

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  include M
  puts 'after including M'
end
```

If you try this example in you rails console you will notice that as soon as the module `M` gets included in `class Product` included hook of module run and

`this will be printed when this module will be included inside a class` this is printed on console

after that `after including M` this will be printed on the console.

Also you can try following commands

```
Product.disabled # a scope with name 'disabled' is avaialble because of including the module M
Product.print_class_name # Outputs => 'Product' This method is available to class with the help of module M
Product.new.print_object_class #Outputs => 'Product'
```

It also offers reusability, include this module M in any class and that class gets access to all those methods described in the module.

Whereas your second example is a mere example of basic module

```
module N
  def self.abc
    puts 'basic module'
  end
end
```

Now `abc` method define in module can be accessible using only this module

`N.abc # outputs 'basic module'`

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  include  N
end
```

Product.abc #raises exception, No method found on class Product
Product.new.abc #raises exception, No method found on object of class Product

I hope this may help you understand the concept of module better.
Please let me know if you still have any doubts.

Comment: Why does Product.abc #raise an exception even though it was included? Is it because `#abc` is still only inside the scope of module N, so Product can't call it?

Comment: So a class method HAS to be inside a `self.included` and `base.extend` block whereas instance methods can just be defined normally?

Comment: yes `abc` in still accessible through module only.
When we include a module then the class methods in that module doesn't get included in the class. Those methods are only for the module.

Comment: @stackjlei - you can even define instance methods in the self.included scope also.
As I told you self.included is invoked as soon as you include a module in class
It may be used to define `scopes` for class or when you want to do something when you are including a module.

`module ClassMethods` are also used to declare class methods

Please feel free to ask any doubts if they are still left

Comment: @stackjlei I just added an answer that explains in detail what's going on behind the scenes and why we have the `self.included` block in the first place.

Comment: I don't understand why module instance methods can go through without the `self.included` but class methods need to be inside the `self.included`