# ActiveSupport::Concern running method before/after initialize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport-concern

Does `ActiveSupport::Concern` support a way to run a method before or after the object's constructed.

e.g. to achieve something like

```
Module Benchmarker

  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  before_initialize
    @constructed_at = DateTime.now
  end

end
```

(Note: Not wanting this for ActiveRecord or ActiveController. Just a generic Ruby class within a Rails project.)

Comment: Nope. AS::Concern doesn't do any before/after callbacks. Also you mean "initializer", not "constructor". It does not _create_ the object.

Comment: Thanks. AFAIK "constructor" and "initialize(r)" are used interchangeably in Ruby, but updated anyway.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you try to achieve? How do you want to use the concern?

Comment: Had a couple of applications in mind, one being a locking mechanism and one being benchmarking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NOTE: This would work for models or only those classes which inherit from `ActiveRecord`.

Rails does not support a `before_initialize` callback. You could use the [after_initialize](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#after-initialize-and-after-find) callback instead. However, when using it in a concern, you need to mention it in an `included do..end` block. For example, the following code should work for your use case:

```
Module Benchmarker
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    after_initialize do |subject|
      p "I'm in after_initialize"
    end
  end
end
```

You could refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28009772/ruby-modules-included-do-end-block) for more details on how the `included` hook works.

Comment: Where does this `after_initialize` come from?

Comment: It is one of the callbacks provided by Rails. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#after-initialize-and-after-find
The code in `after_initialize` gets triggered as soon as we instantiate an object.

Comment: There's no such thing as "rails provides". Rails is a huge monster, consisting of many many smaller libs. Your link points to a page titled "Active Record callbacks". Note that active record is not mentioned in the question. If a class is not an activerecord (or does not include the relevant activemodel module), it does not get that callback.

Comment: Well, Activesupport is mentioned in the question, and that is definitely part of Rails. Link: https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activesupport
Also, the question is tagged as a "Ruby on Rails" question. Hence, the usage of ActiveRecord is justified

Comment: "the usage of ActiveRecord is justified" - no, it's not. Not every class in a rails app is an activerecord. Some rails apps don't even have activerecord loaded. And activesupport by itself doesn't offer these callbacks.

Comment: Added a note mentioning the usage in only those classes that include ActiveRecord

Comment: Yes, note is good, but, IMHO, it deserves a more prominent position. Like, at the very top, and in bold font :)

Comment: Agreed! @SergioTulentsev